# changes in xib causing crash

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, xcodebuild

Changes in xib causing it to crash.
I am using xcode 4 (ie. version 4.0.2) to write a program that I started in earlier versions.
I have written a lot of code and apart from frequent crashes during debug, all was fine.
Then I make some changes in one xib file, and ever since it fails to run; terminating in the main function on line `int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);` with error `Thread 1: Program received signal: 'SIGABRT'`

I dont know what is causing this, I need help.

Comment: Update the question with the complete crash log. And read the faqs and accept some answers.

Comment: @Viraj. Crash Log: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/chiemekailo/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/FC2E630A-6FD5-4F05-8F71-3B70A0973F6E/AandM.app> (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''

Answer (score 0):

What about programmatically loading the nib? Just change nil to your nib's name.

```
CustomViewController* customViewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]
```